# UISplitViewController, make MasterView appear programmatically in portrait iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement a SplitViewController in iOS 8, but due to the nature of my DetailView (horizontal collectionview), the default behavior (swiping from left to right) for making the MasterView visible can't be used.

So now I'm trying to implement this behavior programmaticaly. I've tried to send a swipe gesture to the root view of the DetailView, but this won't do it either. I've looked through some of the answers here on SO. Most of them suggest using the method:

`[splitviewcontroller willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];`

This method is however deprecated in iOS 8.

Any help/lead on the matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to make the MasterView appear without a swipe in portrait mode.

`[self.splitViewController setPreferredDisplayMode:UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay];`